# Formula to populate data in summary sheet based on Month

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a workbook with 6 subjects that I am tracking data.  Each subject has a separate worksheet.  The same data is pulled from multiple sources each month and then compiled into these worksheets. Once all that data has been entered into the subject worksheets, a summary sheet is created, where it pulls the percentages from each of the subject worksheets.

I would like to be able to enter a month in B2 of the summary sheet and then have it auto populate with the data from the subject sheets.

In the subject worksheets, each worksheet is set up with the months starting with column B(Jan) and ending with Column M (Dec).

In column A, the data information is listed 
A3-Name of Test, A4 - Number of Questions, A5 - Number Correct, and A6 - Percentage

There are several "tests" that are listed in column A

For January,  in all subject worksheets, cell B3 would be blank, B4 would have the number of questions, B5 would have the number of correct answers, and in cell B6 it would list the percentage correct.

For February, in all subject worksheets, cell C3 would be blank, C4 would have the number of questions, C5 would have the number of correct answers, and in cell C6 it would list the percentage correct.

On the Summary Sheet, it each subject is listed in the columns B1 - G1.  Cell A2 lists the test,  and A3 asks for the percentage.

For cells B3-G3 it would pull the data from b6 each respective subject worksheet.

In January it would gather the data from B6 from each subject worksheet. In February, it would gather the data from C6, and so on.

Any assistance that anyone can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. May I suggest you try recording a macro and bring back the code and ask for help tweaking it.

Answer (score 0):

@IndyMom83

Convert the data in your six sheets into tables.  Insert > Table > Specify Range.

After your table(s) have been created then you can name these tables using the name manager found under Formulas > Defined Names > Name Manager.

Point your logic functions to the named tables.  Now that your summary tab has some dynamically named fields that are in usage, you can adjust your logic to be date driven.  I would suggest using INDEX(), and MATCH() as a starting point for this type of dashboard and well as EOMONTH() & MONTH().